# C#: Try, Catch not catching exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a try catch that should catch an exception if the string has invalid characters for a Windows path.

```
         try
            {
                Result = Path.GetFullPath(pathname);
            }

            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                CatchResult = (e);
            }
```

But an exception is still being thrown, and the application crash's. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exception which is being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN states that the `Path.GetFullPath()` throws 5 kinds of exceptions but not `IOException`. You must catch the correct type of exception. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: [`PathTooLongException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is derived from `IOException`, so his catch would get that one.

Answer (score 2):

Path.GetFullPath(string) does not throw IOException as one of it's available exceptions.

Please review the Exception list at [Path.GetFullPath MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Exceptions thrown:

1. ArgumentException
2. SecurityException
3. ArgumentNullException
4. NotSupportedException
5. PathTooLongException.

Comment: To be fair, [`PathTooLongException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a descendant of `IOException`, so the catch would get that one.